# Android Simple HTTP Request?

Tags: java, android, apache, http, request

I have this code for an Android application I'm trying to create into interact with my PHP website. I have the *android.permission.INTERNET* permission activated and it keeps creating a toast that says "ERROR." instead of the contents of the website. Here is my only java file:

```
package com.http.request;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HttprequestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private String doHTTPRequest(String url){
        String results = "ERROR";
        try
        {
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);

            if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                results = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String results = doHTTPRequest("http://www.yahoo.com");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), results, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What Android version is your app running on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check to make sure that,

1. If there is an exception being thrown, investigate what is causing the IOException
2. Your server could potentially be returning a non-200 response code.

Put in some breakpoints and see whats happening there. My bet is on the response code.

Comment: The emulator or device is connected to the internet ? Check and see if you can browse yahoo.com on that device.

Answer (score 1):

That is your own "ERROR" string which the `Toast()` displays. Better change

```
catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

to

```
catch(IOException e){
        result = "ERROR IOException";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The exception is thrown as you try to connect in the main thread which is not permitted. Put `doHTTPRequest()` in a thread or `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

What is your stacktrace says, LogCat? What is the error? Add more info, make it more clear to understand than "guessing of coffee beans"

My guess is: this happens because you are trying to do network operation in UI thread which is not allowed in 3.0+ versions.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html